# Collect the digits numbers in the decimal number C#

Tags: c#

I want a method to remove the comma from the decimal number and then collect the digits. For example, if the user inputs `1,3` it will remove the comma and collect `1` and `3` together. I mean 1+3 =4. Can I use trim or replace?

```
public int AddSum(string x1)
{
    string x = x1.Trim();
        
    int n = Convert.ToInt32(x);
    return n;
}
```

Comment: Alright, and what's the part you're having trouble with? Stack Overflow isn't a code-writing service where you input English and get C# in return, the least we need is code you've already attempted to write that has an identifiable problem.

Comment: seems like a typical [homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) to me. can you please share what you've tried and researched so far? we'll gladly help if you're stuck somewhere, but you should first attempt to solve the task on your own - and be able to describe your efforts.  i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: `can i use trim or replace?` - i'd suggest reading the documentation for [Trim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim?view=net-6.0) and [Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=net-6.0), looking at the examples, and figuring out whether or not those are useful... but **please** read the other articles i've linked to, as well.

Comment: ... and remove C# from the title. You've already tagged the question with C# as you should, and we don't like when that's repeated in the title. By the way, welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: String.Split is a good place to start. Also, you probably mean numbers rather than digits, though can't tell for sure.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int AddSum(string x1)
{
    var digitFilter = new Regex(@"[^\d]");        
    return digitFilter.Replace(x1, "").Select(c => int.Parse(c)).Sum();
}
```

OR

```
public int AddSum(string x1)
{
    return x1.Where(c => char.IsDigit(c)).Select(c => c - '0').Sum();
}
```

Comment: Not enough trolling: please add proper conversion of Unicode "" to numbers - i.e. "߁" is a valid digit with proper `Char.GetNumericValue` value but clearly not going to produce sensible result with `c - '0'`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate over the characters in a string and compute the sum of digits contained therein, it's trivial:

```
public static int SumOfDigits( string s ) {
  int n = 0;
  foreach ( char c in s ) {
    n += c >= '0' && c <= '9' // if the character is a decimal digit
      ? c - '0'               // - convert to its numeric value
      : 0                     // - otherwise, default to zero
      ;                       // and add that to 'n'
  }
  return n;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want take a comma-separated string of numbers, add the numbers together, then return the result.

The first thing you have to do is use the `Split()` method on the input string. The `Split()` method takes an input string splits the string into an array of strings based on a character:

```
string[] numbers = x1.Split(',');
```

So now we have an array of strings called `numbers` that hold each number. The next thing you have to do is create an empty variable to hold the running total:

```
int total = 0;
```

The next thing is to create a loop that will iterate through the `numbers` array and each time, add the number to the running total. Remember that `numbers` is an array of *strings* and not numbers. so we must use the `Parse()` method of `int` to convert the string to a number:

```
foreach (string number in numbers)
{
    total += int.Parse(number);
}
```

Finally, just return the result:

```
return total;
```

Put it all together and you got this:

```
private static int AddSum(string x1)
{
    string[] numbers = x1.Split(',');
    int total = 0;
    
    foreach (string number in numbers)
    {
        total += int.Parse(number);
    }
    
    return total;
}
```

I hope this helps and clarifies things. Keep in mind that this method doesn't do any kind of error checking, so if your input is bad, you'll get an exception probably.